# Class name isn't being inserted on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert `animated fadeIn` when the user hovers over the div with a class of `project-title-wrapper`. I only want the instance they are hovering over to change.

My current code is:

```
$(function() {
    var animationName = 'animated fadeIn';
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    $('.project-title-wrapper').on('hover', function() {
        $('.project-title-wrapper').addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass(animationName);
        });
   });
});
```

This doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
$(function() {
    var animationName = 'animated fadeIn';
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    $('.project-title-wrapper').hover(function() {
        $('.project-title-wrapper').addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
            $(this).removeClass(animationName);
        });
    });
});
```

However, this changes every instance

Thanks in advance

Comment: `).one(` try `on` instead and check your console for errors.

Comment: What is animationEnd variable? Are they events?

Comment: changing to `on` results in a `Parsing error`. `animationEnd` are css vendor prefixes for stopping animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `this` keyword to get just the hovered instance.

```
$('.project-title-wrapper').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass(animationName);
    });
});
```

I'd also change out the [`.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method for a more simple `.on('mouseenter')` as using the `.hover` method triggers on both `mouseenter` and `mouseout` which means the class will get added when the user stops hovering as well (leading to some interesting behavior when the user hovers over a thing, pauses until the animation ends, and then hovers over the next thing).

Further, as I cannot see a reason to constantly bind and unbind the `animationEnd` handlers, I'd write it like this:

```
$('.project-title-wrapper').on(animationEnd, function() {
    $(this).removeClass(animationName);
}).on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass(animationName);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    var animationName = 'animated fadeIn';
    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

    $('.project-title-wrapper').on(animationEnd, function() {
        $(this).removeClass(animationName);
    }).on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).addClass(animationName);
    });
});
```

```css
.project-title-wrapper {
  background-color: #060;
  height: 3em;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.project-title-wrapper.animated.fadeIn {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    background-color: #060;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  to {
    background-color: #0D0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-title-wrapper">First</div>
<div class="project-title-wrapper">Second</div>
<div class="project-title-wrapper">Third</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pete, this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

using `$(this)` will apply the classes to the hovered item.  It's a little unclear why you are then listening to `animationEnd` as there is nothing in your code that is going to trigger any animation.

```js
$(function() {
  var animationName = 'animated fadeIn';
  var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

  $('.project-title-wrapper').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass(animationName).one(animationEnd, function() {
      $(this).removeClass(animationName);
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.project-title-wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project-title-wrapper">
  one
</div>

<div class="project-title-wrapper">
  two
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much there, but! On hover, I get the expected result. However, `animated fadeIn` disappears straight after it's activated. When I move my cursor away from the div, it reactivates, albeit for a second. I am trying to have `animated fadeIn` there whilst the cursor is over the div. And remove itself, once the cursor is moved away.